# Get direct descendants in materialized path in MongoDB using regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB collection, I have materialized path tree model like:

```
",Books,Programming,Databases,NoSQL,"
",Books,Programming,Databases,SQL,"
```

For fetching all descendants of `Programming` used:

```
db.categories.find( { path: /,Programming,/ } )
```

Is any availability to create request that will find only direct descendants `Programming`? I.e. will find records with `Databases` but not with `NoSQL` and `SQL`.

Comment: I guess you can try using `/,Programming,[^,]+$/`. If there is a comma at the end, add it: `/,Programming,[^,]+,$/`.

Comment: Thanks! `/,Programming,[^,]+,$/` - works for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
/,Programming,[^,]+,$/
```

The `[^,]+,` pattern matches 1 or more symbols other than a comma (`[^,]+`) and the `,` matches a literal comma. `$` is the end-of-string anchor.

Comment: Thanks, for explanation.